# measuring from ground to an open wire = 0 volts?

Tags: voltage

On a car, if you connect your DVOM to battery neg and connect to an open wire you read 0V, why? A DVOM reads differences in potential. Does the open wire have potential in it? 
Thanks

Comment: What would be putting the potential in the open wire? Unless there is inductance from some nearby source, there really isn't a difference in potential there.

Comment: open wire can have a voltage potential relative to another object. it could be charged like a capacitor. you would need a very sensitive instrument to measure it though . a DVM would drain the charge during measurement ..... unless you are talking about a lot of wire ....  ..... what you are technically doing is holding the two DVM probes in the air and sort of expecting a reading ... battery negative is ground only as far as the vehicle equipment is concerned, it is not a ground to anything outside of that closed system

Comment: A wire has two ends. Is the other end of your “open wire” connected to anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a multimeter measures voltage it *essentially* does the following:

1. Puts a high resistance in **in parallel** with what you are trying to measure
2. Takes a very small current (that goes through the high resistance)
3. Measures the voltage across that high resistance

For all pedantic people, it doesn't *put* the resistance there, it was always there, it's the input impedance of the multimeter, the act of putting it in parallel is when you, the user, connects the multimeter to the two voltage potentials you are trying to measure.

---

Here's a step-by-step of (following the above steps) when you attempt to measure two voltage potentials that has **nothing** to do with each other.

1. Same as above, no problem at all.
2. hmmmm how can you take some current from nothing? You can't, so you will get 0 Ampere through your high resistance. All charges will balance themselves, you will not be able to see the charge moving from one potential to the other.
3. According to ohm's law we know that \$V=I×R\$, if \$I = 0\$, then \$V = 0\$. So you will measure 0 Volt.

---

In order to measure anything you need to take a piece of what you are trying to measure. Had you **not** measured anything then they would have had some voltage potential, be it some atto Volts or a couple hundred volts. But by putting your multimeter across the two voltage potentials you also allow the electrons to move from one to the other through the high resistance. Without any voltage / current source, it will balance out and you will read 0 Volt.

It's like measuring a capacitor, when you do so you are discharging it, so if there's some charge and some capacitance you can see on your multimeter as the voltage goes down.

Your measurement is like measuring a capacitor, however if there's barely any charge and next to zero capacitance as in your example, then your "capacitor" will discharge almost instantly.